# How do we interpret Mesa compiler error message?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, mesa

I have built MESA with OpenSWR on Windows. I am getting an error in my shader code that I cannot understand/correct. The same code runs fine using just GLEW/Nvidia drivers.

Here's the error message:

> name= identfshader, error= 0:27(8): error: syntax error, unexpected NEW_IDENTIFIER, expecting ',' or ';'

If I understand this correctly, the problem occurs in line 27, column 8. Is this what 0:27(8) stands for?

If somebody could explain to me how to determine the line number in the shader code where this is happening I'll be happy to post a snippet of that part of the code for further help.

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly 27 is the line and 8 the column which causes the error, but since the glsl code is compiled by graphics driver, this depends on.If you would publish the code, someone would be there to help you.

Comment: You are right. Those are the line/column numbers, but the message is so poor it doesn't tell me anything. I finally figured out what was wrong with my glsl code by relying on these numbers. But the message was useless in the end.